# Wowza Media Server Performance

Tags: performance, server, wowza

I am using wowza for live streaming , I have server with this hardware

> Architecture:          x86_64
>
> CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
>
> Byte Order:            Little Endian
>
> CPU(s):                40
>
> On-line CPU(s) list:   0-39
>
> Thread(s) per core:    2
>
> Core(s) per socket:    10
>
> Socket(s):             2
>
> NUMA node(s):          2
>
> Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
>
> CPU family:            6
>
> Model:                 63
>
> Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v3 @ 2.60GHz
>
> Stepping:              2
>
> CPU MHz:               1202.804
>
> CPU max MHz:           3300.0000
>
> CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
>
> BogoMIPS:              5189.36
>
> Virtualisation:        VT-x
>
> L1d cache:             32K L1i cache:             32K L2 cache:
>   256K L3 cache:              25600K
>
> NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-9,20-29 NUMA node1 CPU(s):     10-19,30-39

and I have more than 10,000 connection but when i get 500 or 600 connection my video stream cutting I think wowza default tune can not help me , please whats best tune for my need . or is the server enagh ??? any advice please

Comment: are you transrating/transcoding? did you monitor the server when this happens,  what about the cpu&ram levels?

Comment: Iam not transcoding , and when the problem happen server is ok

Comment: Maybe there is some limitation or ... I dont know  Iam new in wowza

Comment: what about the Bandwidth?  maybe your provider limits this.  if the streams use 1Mbps per user,  with 500 user you are using 500Mbps,  many datacenter providers limit this.

Comment: the bandwidth  is 10GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be experiencing a Java performance tuning issue. Take a look at the article on performance tuning at https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-do-performance-tuning to see if it is helpful.

If that does not help, or you've already followed these steps, this is likely more of an administration question than a coding question. If so, you can find answers and assistance on the Wowza forums, at https://www.wowza.com/community/ , or submit a free helpdesk request by signing into your account portal page at https://www.wowza.com/portal/help/engine .

I hope this helps...

-Chris